# What do I need (powerwise) to plug my French gamer PC in Canada

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I read on metastack that superuser is the place to ask hardware related stuff, hope it fits.

I recently move from France to Canada and I'm going to get my gamer PC shipped soon.

What will I need to plug it to the wall ?
The numbers are :
France : 230V@50Hz
Canada : 110@60Hz
My PC : ~500W

I'm sure only an adapter wont do the trick, will a transformer 110V to 220V be enough, or do I need to change my power supply ?

Same questions goes for the screens (they both have integrated AC-DC transformer).

Any help is appreciated thx !

Comment: You haven’t supplied enough information.  Power supply specifications are required to answer this question

Comment: Check the specs on your power supply. Many (most?) accept AC input in the range 100-240 V and 50-60 Hz.

Comment: Most modern power supplies are "universal" and will accept 110 to 240V and hopefully just needs a different mains lead. Open up your pc or check the label on the back.

Comment: Thx for the info, I don't have the pc on me right now, but I'll be sure to check that